# Use Pure Bootstrap v4 on ReactJs is NOT working

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, react-router-v4

I was desperately want to use pure Bootstrap v4 on my React.js app. I created my app using create-react-app. So, i put Bootstrap assets on index.html (in public folder).

At the first try, it was working well. Then, i added some dependencies like `react-router-dom`, `react-router-config`, and `prop-types`. Suddenly, it displayed almost a blank page.

**1) Project Folder**

[image]

**2) kodebaru/webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src/index.jsx'),

  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist/js'),
    filename: 'app.js',
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, '/client/src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ["react", "es2015"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  watch: true
};
```

**3) kodebaru/server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './backend/static/')));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, './client/dist/')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './backend/static/', 'index.html'));
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3500;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

**4) kodebaru/backend/static/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Kodebaru</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**5) result**

[image]

**6) Warning Message**

[image]

I knew there is a framework bootstrap for react app ([reactstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovl0K.png)). But, this time i want to know how to use pure bootstrap v4 in react app ?

Comment: Is there any console errors ? What is the html rendered ?

Comment: @Panther .. it is nothing

Comment: if there is nothing rendered, then the server did not send any data ? Show some fiddle or location to check !

Comment: @Panther .. i've added the details

Comment: Looks like the problem lies with the CSS. There are nav related tags and they are not displayed. Inspect and find out why it is not visible on the UI

Comment: @Panther .. i got warning message on Chrome developer tool. Please check on my question. i've update it.

Comment: That warning is ignorable. Its related to map file. You have to check your applied css on the DOM.

Comment: I replicated what was laid out in your question with the exception of the react components as I obviously don't have the source for those. Your basic setup seems sound in so much as it worked for me. I'd try working your way backwards, move back a few commits in your source control, or remove packages you added recently and see what happens. If none of that works, try referencing bootstrap from a CDN instead of your local copy in case something odd happened to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is too late. But, i think it is good to answer my own question since there is no one. The solution was to install bootstrap using npm, import bootstrap on index.jsx, add `jQuery`, `Popper.js`, and `css loader` on webpack configuration file.

**a) Install bootstrap using npm**

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
```

**b) Import bootstrap on index.jsx**

```
import 'bootstrap';
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

**c) Add jQuery and Popper.js on webpack**

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
     $: 'jquery',
     jQuery: 'jquery',
     'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
     Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
})
```

**d) Add css loader on webpack**

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
}
```

The full implementation is below :

1) index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import promise from "redux-promise";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from 'react-router-config';
import routes from './routes.js';
import reducers from './redux/reducers/index.js'
import 'bootstrap';
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

const createStoreWithMiddleware = createStore(reducers, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(promise)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store = {createStoreWithMiddleware}>
    <Router>
      {/* kick it all off with the root route */}
      {renderRoutes(routes)}
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

if(module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./routes.js', function() {
    routes();
  })
}
```

2) webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './app/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, '/app'),
                exclude: '/node_modules',
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ["react", "es2015"],
                    plugins: [
                        "transform-react-pug",
                        "transform-react-jsx",
                        "transform-object-rest-spread"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html'
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    watch: true
};
```